# How do I mercurial clone from stdin

Tags: unix, 7-zip, clone, mercurial

The mercurial bundle I want to clone from is compressed in 7zip format and I don't want to waste time extracting the gigantic bundle to a temporary file. How do I pass the output of `7za` to `hg` to clone? I tried passing the pipe as a file as suggested by information from [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/398514/338685) like

```
hg clone <(7za x bundle.hg.7z)
```

but I get an error message like

```
abort: repository /dev/fd/63 not found!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that clone doesn't like the pipes, but the `unbunble` command seems to be more friendly. You just need to create the destination repository and unbundle to it.

```
mkdir repo
cd repo
hg init
hg unbundle <(7za x bundle.hg.7z -so)
```